# Can't send emails with Mailgun

Tags: javascript, email, meteor, mailgun

So I just signed up for `Mailgun`, I haven't entered any credit card info neither have I verified a domain name or anything of that sort. I did verify my `Mailgun` account however.

My issue is that for some reason, I can only send emails to the email address I signed up for the `Mailgun` account with. 
E.g. the email I used to set up my account in `Mailgun` is `peppa@gmail.com`, and I can only send emails to `peppa@gmail.com`, if I enter another email address, nothing happens.

Any help is appreciated. My objective is to be able to send emails to any address.

Comment: use sendbox server of them they give you

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate issue [Mailgun API works only with one email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261874/mailgun-api-works-only-with-one-email/)

You have verified your domain to send an email to other emails.
for more read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261874/mailgun-api-works-only-with-one-email/44342345#44342345)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Mailgun [documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#verify-your-domain) you have to verify your domain in order to be able to send emails. 
Most SMTP providers do so in order to limit spam.

Once your domain is verified you should be able to send emails from this domain to any address.

Answer (score 0):

This is how mailgun is designed to lessen spam and to protect its reputation. You can identify any email to work with your sandbox email, but until you verify your domain you will not have full functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Let's be honest here - even if you use a verified email it is still an awful service that doesn't tell you why it doesn't bother to send anything. API is awful - avoid MailGun.